# What is the purpose of England national football C team?

Tags: football

I read a football magazine a few years ago and there was an article about England national football C team. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England_national_football_C_team), this team represents England at non-league level.

As far as I know, a national football team was formed to represent the country in international competitions like World Cup and in the case of England, Euro or Nations League. Since it has been represented by the senior national football team, what is the purpose of the England C team?

Comment: I suspect it is the old England Amateur side. At one time amateur football existed as a separate sporting entity. In practice it is virtually impossible to regulate what is amateur and what is professional. But the idea of "amateur" is retained, for example in the teams which compete for the FA Vase - which I THINK is the same thing that used to be known as the FA Amateur Cup. It is the first time I have heard of the "C team" - but it seems to me that is what it is.